# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in angular 11

Tags: angular

I have created function for search data in array object using angular 11.

Its showing the error while on keydown function.

while creating search function its showing console error.

in html file

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="archivedpollSearch" placeholder="{{ 'FIFTH_ITERATION.MY_COMMUNITIES.SEARCH_ARCHIVED_POLLS' | translate}}"
        class="search-input border-0 bg-transparent" (keydown)="searchArchivePolls()">



<mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0 panelExpansion border-top border-bottom border-right border-left" *ngFor="let archives of archivedPoll;let i= index">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title translate>{{archives?.question}}</mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-description *ngFor="let options of archives?.CM_Poll_Options;let i=index">
          <div class="radio-group widthRadio" *ngIf="options?.pollId==archives?.id">
            <label class="container poll-done">
              {{options?.pollOption}}  
              <input  type="radio" name="polls" [checked]="archives?.CM_Poll_Results[i]?.choice==options?.id && archives?.CM_Poll_Results[i].userId ==this.userId">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
              <small>{{(options?.percentageValue | number) || 0}} %</small>
              <div [style.width]="options.percentageValue + '%' "></div>
            </label>
      </div>
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

In my ts file

```
searchArchivePolls(){  
    if(this.archivedpollSearch.length >= 1){
      this.archivedPoll.map((poll, index)=>{
        if(poll.question.includes(this.archivedpollSearch)){              
          this.archivedPoll = poll; 
          console.log(this.archivedPoll);     
        }
      })
    }else{
      this.getArchivePolls();
    }
  }
```

getArchivePolls function called in ngOninit

I need to use search for array object values.

Here is my server side response

```
[
    {
        "id": 179,
        "question": "archived poll2?",
        "communityId": 198,
        "userPollCount": 1,
        "CM_Poll_Options": [
            {
                "id": 394,
                "pollId": 179,
                "pollOption": "archived1",
                "percentageValue": "100.0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 395,
                "pollId": 179,
                "pollOption": "archived2",
                "percentageValue": "0.0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 396,
                "pollId": 179,
                "pollOption": "archived3",
                "percentageValue": "0.0000"
            },
            {
                "id": 397,
                "pollId": 179,
                "pollOption": "archived4",
                "percentageValue": "0.0000"
            }
        ],
        "CM_Poll_Results": [
            {
                "userId": 6,
                "choice": 394,
                "CM_Users": {
                    "id": 6,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 178,
        "question": "testing question for archive polls?",
        "communityId": 198,
        "userPollCount": 0,
        "CM_Poll_Options": [
            {
                "id": 392,
                "pollId": 178,
                "pollOption": "testing1",
                "percentageValue": null
            },
            {
                "id": 393,
                "pollId": 178,
                "pollOption": "testing2",
                "percentageValue": null
            }
        ],
        "CM_Poll_Results": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop over `archivedPoll` with `ngFor` but you're assigning it to an object here:

```js
  this.archivedPoll.map((poll, index)=>{
        if(poll.question.includes(this.archivedpollSearch)){              
          this.archivedPoll = poll; // <-- here
          console.log(this.archivedPoll);     
        }
      })
```

I think you're trying to create a new array from `archivedPoll` so this might be better:

```js
const archivedPolls = this.archivedPoll.map((poll, index)=>{
  if(poll.question.includes(this.archivedpollSearch)){              
    return poll;     
  }
})

this.archivedPoll = archivedPolls;
```

Comment: i have tried to do search option, if i enter testing only second object should return in my example response